# Missing or broken reference to the file 'MSADODC.OCX' version 6.0

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Recently I started my old project run on my PC, I tried to run the project, and I got this *error*:

```
Your Microsoft Office Access database or project contains a missing or broken reference to the file 'MSADODC.OCX' version 6.0
* To ensure that your database or project works properly, you must fix this reference.
```

I have resumed this old project after two years, So I don't know what code my mistake might be on

**Why do I have this Error and How can I solve it?**

Comment: I'd start by **[checking](https://www.google.com/search?q=Missing+or+broken+reference+to+the+file+'MSADODC.OCX'+version+6.0)** if anyone else has had this problem before, and what they did to overcome it.

Comment: (@ashleedawg) here's a broader search which may help: https://www.google.com/search?q=vb6+missing+or+broken+reference&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS813US813&oq=vb6+missing+or+broken+reference&aqs=chrome..69i64.3880j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8  This is a common type of VB6 error, probably nothing really specific to msadodc.ocx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Missing or Broken reference is not an error in your VBA code specifically, it is an error indicating that a library (or in this case an ActiveX Control) that you are using in your project is missing.

This means that the MSADODC.OCX ActiveX Control file is not in the location Access expects it to be, nor can it resolve that location by the Registration of that control in the Windows Registry.

You can view your References and the path that Access thinks the MSADODC.OCX file should be by:

1. Open the VBA Editor in your Access file
2. Click on the `Tools` menu and choose `References`

You should get a dialog similar to the following:

[image: Access References Dialog]

Notice the `MISSING:` text next to several of the References listed.  That means that Access cannot resolve those libraries.  When you click on the `MISSING` reference, the bottom section shows you the path where Access expected that file to be located.

Your MSADODC.OCX ActiveX control should show in your References dialog.

To resolve the MISSING reference, you will likely need to re-install VB6 or re-register the OCX file if you can find it on your hard drive.

If you find it, you can re-register it (assuming all DLL dependencies for the OCX are present) by using Regsvr32.exe (Microsoft - [How to use Regsvr32 tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/249873/how-to-use-the-regsvr32-tool-and-troubleshoot-regsvr32-error-messages))

Usually, open a command prompt (with Administrative privileges), navigate to the folder containing the OCX file and issue:

```
regsvr32 msadodc.ocx
```

I hope this helps.

**Update 1** I forgot to mention that it may be possible that you don't actually need the reference to MSADODC.OCX in your project, but you would have to determine that by removing it and compiling your code (to see if any errors are found), and by checking all of your forms to make sure the control isn't contained on them.

In Microsoft Access, if you add an ActiveX Control to a Form, Access adds a reference to that control.  However, if you then delete that ActiveX Control from your Form, Access does not remove the reference.  If you are no longer using the control, you have to remove the reference yourself by unchecking it in the dialog shown above.